# Does Ajax make actual GET calls to server and if so why does it not show up on Firebug?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a LAMP setup on my Ubuntu and I am trying to connect to print it out in an unordered list using Ajax. It does not, however print out anything and I don't see any calls to server on my Firebug.

If it helps, this is my HTML file making the call:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title Woo!</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>Paragraph.</p>


        <ul></ul>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $.getJSON('DbGetter.php', function(data) {
                        $.each(data, function(key, array) {
                                $('ul').append('<li id="' + key + '">' 
                                + array.longitude + ' ' 
                                + array.latitude + '</li>');
                        });
                });

        });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my php file which should be receiving the call:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "testuser";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "Locations";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM places";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row

    $array = array()

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $place = array(
        'id' => $row["id"], 
        'latitude'=> $row["latitude"] , 
        'longitude'=> $row["longitude"], 
        'place_name' => $row["place_name"],
        'country_code'=> $row["country_code"], 
        'postal_code'=> $row["postal_code"]);


        echo "Coordinates: " . $row["latitude"]. " " . $row["longitude"]. " - Name: " . $row["place_name"]. "   " .  "<br>";

        array_push($array, $place);

    }
        echo json_encode($array);
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Current state of the php file:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "testuser";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "Locations";

header('Content-Type: application/json');

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM places";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    //declare associative array
    $array = array();
    $num = 0;

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        //store them in an array
        $place = array(
        'id' => $row["id"], 
        'latitude'=> $row["latitude"] , 
        'longitude'=> $row["longitude"], 
        'place_name' => $row["place_name"],
        'country_code'=> $row["country_code"], 
        'postal_code'=> $row["postal_code"]);


        /*
        echo "Coordinates: " . $row["latitude"]. " " . $row["longitude"]. " - Name: " . $row["place_name"]. "   " .  "<br>";
        */

        //building the second associative array
        $array[$num] = $place;
        $num += 1;

    }

        echo json_encode($array);
} else {
    echo json_encode("0 results");
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Any errors in browser console?

Comment: Nothing. But it does detect errors in other files I tested, though none of them are using Ajax.

Comment: Let's add a `console.log` immediately after `$.getJSON('DbGetter.php', function(data) {` to see what is actually getting returned.  An HTTP GET call is being made to your server.  It's response is what you are calling `data`.

Comment: I use chrome dev tools and you would see the HTTP request in the network tab.

Comment: The response is not valid JSON because of your `echo` statements.

Comment: @harris, that is not true.  It is a valid response.

Comment: @harris have right. You cannot echo values, you need to echo json_encode content only. Second problem is that you need to set header content. `header('Content-Type: application/json');` just before the `echo` part.

Comment: @pr0metheus, no.  The response is `json_encode`'d.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah try to set header content as json

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah Only part of it. There are additional echo statements in the while loop that make it invalid JSON.

Comment: @harris, Yes, I missed that. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a parse error in your PHP code which is most likely causing a server 500 error.  Nothing is echoed as a result.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row

    $array = array()  // Missing semi-colon

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

In Chrome, a server 500 error shows up in the console as an error even if you don't handle it. I'm not sure how Firefox handles a server 500 error. Chain a `fail` method to handle the error yourself. Also, while debugging, `console.log` the response in the case of a success to see what is actually being returned.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $.getJSON('DbGetter.php', function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $.each(data, function(key, array) {
                            $('ul').append('<li id="' + key + '">' 
                            + array.longitude + ' ' 
                            + array.latitude + '</li>');
                    });
            })
            .fail(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
            });

    });
</script>
```

And yes, this AJAX request does make an actual HTTP GET request to the server (`/DbGetter.php`).

In your PHP file, be sure to `json_encode` all echo statements so that jQuery will be able to interpret the response properly.  Also, ensure that what you are returning is valid JSON.

You will need to build an associative array and return it, just as you did with `$place`. Get rid of the non `json_encode`'d echo statements.

Comment: Should I also use json_encode() on the else statement and if so why not? And why do I have to make it an associative array to pass it through? Does it have to do with the way json encodes variables?

Comment: Yes, you should use json_encode for all echoed statements.  And yes, the associate array translates to a JSON object.

Comment: I now get the 200 but I also get a "parsererror".
I've added:
the header to the php
the second associative array
commented out the non-json encoded echos
I added
    `try {
         JSON.parse(str);
      } catch (e) {
         console.log('Not JSon')
      }`
to the html file.

Comment: I've also eddited the current state of the php in the original post. (Should I make a different question now that it's not really about the whether Ajax sends GET requests anymore)

Comment: Yes, please.  I'm at work now, but please link the question here and I will try to answer it later if it hasn't already been answered.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398102/php-files-sending-only-a-parsererror-through-ajax right here