# PHP files sending only a "parsererror" through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

SOLUTION: After a teamviewer session with @skobaljic he figured out that I was not actually opening the html in localhost but using the file system (as in file://...). I apologize for wasting everyone's time like that.

I am trying to send some php arrays through Ajax and print them out and despite getting a 200 OK response, there is no actual effect in the received html. The status text says "parsererror".

The files are the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title Woo!</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>Paragraph.</p>


        <ul></ul>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $.getJSON('DbGetter.php', function(data) {


                    console.log(data);
                    $.each(data, function(key, array) {
                            $('ul').append('<li id="' + key + '">' 
                            + array.longitude + ' ' 
                            + array.latitude + '</li>');
                    });
            })
            .fail(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
            });

        });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the php:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "testuser";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "Locations";

header('Content-Type: application/json');

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM places";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    //declare associative array
    $array = array();
    $num = 0;

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        //store them in an array
        $place = array(
        'id' => $row["id"], 
        'latitude'=> $row["latitude"] , 
        'longitude'=> $row["longitude"], 
        'place_name' => $row["place_name"],
        'country_code'=> $row["country_code"], 
        'postal_code'=> $row["postal_code"]);


        /*
        echo "Coordinates: " . $row["latitude"]. " " . $row["longitude"]. " - Name: " . $row["place_name"]. "   " .  "<br>";
        */

        //building the second associative array
        $array[$num] = $place;
        $num += 1;

    }

        echo json_encode($array);
} else {
    echo json_encode("0 results");
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

I've tried looking at the value through firebug, but either I'm blind or it's just not stored anywhere in the DOM. I'm pretty new to web application in general so I don't know how to go about debugging it.

Running the php by itself I get: `[{"id":"1","latitude":"57.0502","longitude":"9.9173","place_name":"1000fryd","c‌​ountry_code":"DK","postal_code":"9000"},{"id":"2","latitude":"58.0502","longitude‌​":"10.9173","place_name":"same_place","country_code":"DK","postal_code":"9000"}]` 
Which are the 2 rows I expect.

There is also no XHR request marked by Firebug.

Comment: PLease take a look into the http servers error log file. That is where you can simply read what is wrong at exactly what line of code in which file.

Comment: @JayBlanchard http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#language.operators.assignment there (same as my whhhhat link)

Comment: I read that @Dale, maybe I shouldn't use "concept".

Comment: @JayBlanchard No worries champ :)

Comment: I did @arkascha and I retracted my comment. I automatically went for the mathematic operators. My bad.

Comment: At which point do you get the error message? Can you run the PHP by itself?

Comment: Can you show us your actual JSON output?

Comment: Running the php by itself I get:

[{"id":"1","latitude":"57.0502","longitude":"9.9173","place_name":"1000fryd","country_code":"DK","postal_code":"9000"},{"id":"2","latitude":"58.0502","longitude":"10.9173","place_name":"same_place","country_code":"DK","postal_code":"9000"}]

Which are the 2 rows I expect

Comment: Please edit your original post to add any new information.

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` show?

Comment: console.log(data) says nothing. In fact it's never actually called going by firebug

Comment: Then there has to be an error in the console.

Answer (score 1):

You're not encoding valid JSON here.. This will give you a "parseerror" if you try using JQuery's $getJSON with it. Notice the [JQuery Ajax Source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js) from lines 275-281.

```
echo json_encode("0 results");
```

You could probably change it to something like:

```
echo json_encode(["0 results"]);
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote but this looks promising, maybe add a correct way to do it too!

Comment: If you lint this `"0 results"`, it is *valid* JSON. My downvote.

Comment: @JayBlanchard if you use $getJSON from a non properJSON output, you're going to get a parse error.

Comment: In this case it is valid JSON. Give it a test and see. If the JSON was at error the OP's try/catch would've output a different message.

Comment: @JayBlanchard,you are correct that technically it is valid JSON but it won't parse in JS. it doesn't matter if OP used a try catch with his JSON parse. JQuery's internal JSON.parse will catch it and throw an error. a JSON.parse in a try catch is actually redundant. The whole point of using a $getJSON is so that JQuery can parse the JSON before it's handled by the client.

Comment: @JayBlanchard if you're still curious, JQuery has an internal JSON.parse wrapped in a try catch for $getJSON. You can see it here:https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js, it's at lines 275-281 :D

Comment: It works for me. The problem is not here however, it is in his actual JSON output from his query. It never enters the condition where it returns "0 results" BTW, I know how `$getJSON` works ;)

Comment: @JayBlanchard, lol but when I said you were going to get a parse error from using $getJSON, you kept ragging on me. Nevertheless, this is probably the only way you  could get "parseerror" with OP's code. PHP does not callout errors like that and I don't see any other JS code that would invoke that. Perhaps OP doesn't have anything in his DB?

Comment: That would be my guess. Anywho, I removed my DV due to the spirited conversation @wateriswet his `$array` is always *something*, even if it is empty.

Comment: I've put in the brackets and it is still a parse error.

If I run the query in SQL from the command line I get:
+----+--------------+-------------+------------+----------+-----------+
| id | country_code | postal_code | place_name | latitude | longitude |
|  1 | DK           | 9000        | 1000fryd   |  57.0502 |    9.9173 |

|  2 | DK           | 9000        | same_place |  58.0502 |   10.9173 |
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

There are 2 rows.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks man, yes, the array is something, but according to his if statement, if there aren't any rows, it'll output his error string.

Comment: @PavelAndrei could post the Ajax output?

Comment: Running the php by itself I get: [{"id":"1","latitude":"57.0502","longitude":"9.9173","place_name":"1000fryd","co‌​untry_code":"DK","postal_code":"9000"},{"id":"2","latitude":"58.0502","longitude"‌​:"10.9173","place_name":"same_place","country_code":"DK","postal_code":"9000"}] Which are the 2 rows I expect from the html.

Comment: The if statement is for the number of rows selected by his mysql query.
if ($result->num_rows > 0)

Comment: @PavelAndrei is the console outputting "Not JSon" ?

Comment: I don't know how I would get the Ajax output. As I said, I'm using the Firebug extension and I can't find where the output should be. I tried setting a breakpoint when the function starts, but it never actually reaches the "$.getJSON('DbGetter.php', function(data)" line

Comment: Ah - I had missed that @wateriswet - time for me to take a nap.

Comment: the console is not outputing "Not JSon"

Comment: Trying to lint your JSON and it has some hidden characters in it.

Comment: It never even reaches that line, going by the breakpoints but goes through the .fail(function error) branch.

Comment: I also used the output from the php file with https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and it says Valid JSON (RFC 4627)

Comment: Yea, @JayBlanchard is correct, there are some invalid characters in your JSON. I don't know why but it's either an error on your server side or  something that happened when you pasted it into stackoverflow.

Comment: After running the site again I got an error that says "Error: Permission denied to access property "apply"" despite not having changed any of the files at all.

Comment: It's true what I pasted in the comments is invalid, but the actual output from the page is valid. I think I just didn't use the `code` format and that's why.

Comment: That's a cross-origin issue... This seems to be one clusterfk of problems.. And yes, that'd make sense.

Comment: testing
`[{"id":"1","latitude":"57.0502","longitude":"9.9173","place_name":"1000fryd","country_code":"DK","postal_code":"9000"},{"id":"2","latitude":"58.0502","longitude":"10.9173","place_name":"same_place","country_code":"DK","postal_code":"9000"}]`

Comment: your ajax request is actually returning that right?

Comment: Apparently, the "Error: Permission denied to access property "apply"" is just something that happens with firebug and jquera going by what this person says: https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/7996

Comment: Nope, the php file is returning that. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to get the AJAX output. Maybe I'm using Firebug wrong but I don't get how to see the contents of the AJAX function's return.

Comment: Ohhh.. That changes everything, you should be able to find it under XHR requests.

Comment: Did you open firebug after refreshing? Make sure you have it open before you reload so it can catch everything.

Comment: Th only request it has is to jquery, but none under xhr requests. This is turning pretty crazy.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$.getJSON` method, so the data is already parsed correctly. In case you do not get the JSON it would trigger `fail`.

So, just remove:

```
try { JSON.parse(data); } catch (e) { console.log('Not JSon') }
```

Comment: As correct as this is, it would not cause a "parseerror" problem

Comment: I only added that later as a test, just in case something happened to it in-transit that caused it to gain some extra characters or something. It wasn't there to begin with.

Comment: @Pavel, please try to use new version of jQuery, the one you use is old and had issues with parsing JSON.

Comment: I've changed the link to `"<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'></script>"` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try to use pure ajax call, without pointing to json, also remove JSON header from PHP to see what you get actually. Go something like `$.ajax({url: url, success: function(data) {console.log(data) } });`

Comment: I've replaced the script with this:

`<script type='text/javascript'>
        $.ajax({ url: '/DbGetter.php',
         data: {action: 'array'},
         type: 'GET',
         success: function(output) {
                      alert(output);
                  }
  });
        </script>`
I'm not sure how correct it is as I am completely new to web development. I have also commented out the header.

Comment: Setting the url and success callback should be enough. And what do you get as alert? It is better to output into browser console, though. Please note the `'/DbGetter.php'` will point to root file.

Comment: Nothing, same thing as before, really.

Comment: Don't we want it to point to root file? am I supposed to link to http:IP/filename.php instead of file:localhost.php? I tried that and it still doesn't work.